# How to edit ttk style for ttk.OptionMenu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

Recently started using ttk for improving my GUI looks, but i got stuck at editing ttk.OptionMenu style. As I uderstand code below should change background of all Radiobuttons and OptionMenus. For Radiobutton (and other elements I tried) it works just fine, but OptionMenu doesnt change at all.

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("TRadiobutton", background="grey")
s.configure("TOptionMenu", background="grey")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The style name for an OptionMenu is not TOptionMenu. For any widget the style name can get obtained using `widget.winfo_class()` and for an `OptionMenu` this returns `TMenubutton`.

So `s.configure("TMenubutton", background="red")` yields:

[image: OptionMenu with red background]

Comment: How about changing the background color of the dropdown menu? The method you suggested only changes the color of the `Menubutton` when the dropdown menu is not visible

Comment: This is a new question really. Menus did not get themed as part of ttk so use Tk style configuration. That means you can configure the menu using the menus background option. You can get the menu associated with the OptionMenu using `w.nametowidget(w.cget("menu"))` where `w` is the widget instance.

Comment: I didn't mean to say your answer to the main question is not good enough. It is simple and elucidating. Just wanted to take advantage and ask an additional question I am interested in. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

To change the background of the drop down menu:

```
my_optionmenu["menu"].configure(bg="black")
```

If you run:

```
print(my_optionmenu["menu"].keys())
```

you get all of the options you can change for the OptionMenu widget