# Python Tkinter OptionMenu scroll arrows size

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using an OptionMenu to select from many different options, too many to fit on one screen. Tkinter automatically adds up and down arrows to scroll through the list, however I would like to make these arrows larger and easier to click on.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

#create 100 options the user can select from
options = ["Option " + str(x) for x in range(100)]

text = tk.StringVar()
text.set( "Select" )
menu = tk.OptionMenu( root , text , *options)

#set the text size within the menu
menu['menu'].configure(font=('Bahnschrift',20), activeborderwidth=20)
menu.configure(font=('Bahnschrift',20))
menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the result:

[image: This is what I get]

As you can see, the triangle arrows at the top and the bottom of this list are very small, how do I make them bigger, and therefore easier to click on?

Comment: You can use `ttk.Style()` for it and configure the arrow size. [Starting help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41507545/13629335)